# Is this language a context free language?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, context-free, theory

Consider the following language, where the alphabet is $\{0, 1, 2\}$:
$B = \{0^a1^b2^c|a, b, c \geq 0 \text{ and }c = ab + 1\}$.

Is this language a context free language? Prove your answer.

I am having trouble using the pumping lemma of context free languages to show if this language is context free? Can anyone give me any tips or advice on how to approach this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pumping lemma to prove that the language is not context-free. Suppose $B$ is context-free and let $n$ be the constant of the pumping lemma. Consider the word $u = 0^n1^n2^{n^2+1} \in B$. Then we can write $u = vwxyz$ such that:

- $|wxy| \leq n$;
- $|wy| > 0$;
- $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}, vw^kxy^kz \in B$

Now since $|wxy| \leq n$, we either have $wxy\in \{0,1\}^*$ or $wxy\in \{1,2\}^*$. You can then study all the different possibilities and find a contradiction in each case.