# Is this a regular language + context free

Tags: regular-languages, context-free

Is $L_1 = \{0^n1^m0^{n+m}\mid m,n \geq 0\}$ regular? What is its context free grammar and proof?

Second, is the following language context-free?

$$L_2=\{0^a1^b2^c \mid a,b,c \geq 0 \text{ and } c = ab+1 \}$$

I am trying to prove this via the pumping lemma but am stuck. For CFG however, I have no idea. For the context-free language I tried applying CFL pumping lemma but am confused.

Comment: The $c=ab+1$ description in the language looks familiar, probably an exercise somewhere? You can find a suggestion here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/138413/4287

Comment: The usual rule is one question per post.